# For a custom ActivityResultContract, what's the proper way to pass multiple input values?

Tags: android

I'm learning the Activity Results API that replace the `onActivityResult`. I understand the concept and basic usage, but not sure what's the proper way to setup an intent that takes multiple input extras.

For example, I want to put two Boolean flags and one String to the intent, in the old way, I could do

```
Val intent = Intent(this, AnotherActivity::java.class)
intent.putExtra(key1, false)
intent.putExtra(key2, true)
intent.putExtra(key3, someString)
```

But how do I do this in `createIntent` method? And what would the input type for this custom `ActivityResultContract`?

One way I can see is using `Intent` as input type, like `class CustomActivityContract : ActivityResultContract<Intent, Unit>()`. But that doesn't feel right to me.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: What's stopping you from creating whatever strongly typed class you want? That's what [`StartIntentSenderForResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult) does

Comment: @ianhanniballake You are right. Instead of creating the custom ActivityResultContract, I could just use this or `ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult`.

Comment: That's not actually what I said at all. I said there's already an example of a contract that takes a complicated type (much more complicated than two booleans) in a type safe way (which `StartActivityForResult` does not give you).

Comment: Aha, sorry I misunderstood earlier. Ya, I got what you mean now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't call createIntent() directly. Instead, pass your intent to the `ActivityResultLauncher.launch()` method.

```
val launcher = registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
  // handle result
}

launcher.launch(
  Intent(this, AnotherActivity::class.java)
    .putExtra(key1, false)
    .putExtra(key2, true)
    .putExtra(key3, someString)
)
```

Comment: Ya, that's what I mean by declaring `Intent` as the input type, as in `ActivityResultContract<Intent, Unit>`. I guess this is the best way? It feels a bit weird since the `createIntent` is pretty much useless in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a custom data class:

```
data class SomeActivityResultModel(
val foo: String,
val bar: String
)
```

and pass in as an input parameter:

```
class SomeActivityResultContract: ActivityResultContract<SomeActivityResultModel, Unit> {

   override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: SomeActivityResultModel?): Intent {
      return Intent(context, SomeActivity::class.java).apply {
        putExtra("foo", input?.foo)
        putExtra("bar", input?.bar)
      }
   }
}
```

Also you can extend Parcelable or Serializable and pass it whole as extra:

```
@Parselize
    data class SomeActivityResultModel(
    val foo: String,
    val bar: String
    ): Parcelable

class SomeActivityResultContract: ActivityResultContract<SomeActivityResultModel, Unit> {

   override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: SomeActivityResultModel?): Intent {
      return Intent(context, SomeActivity::class.java).apply {
        putExtra("someClass", input)
      }
   }
}
```